# Python seaborn set_style different styles

Tags: python, seaborn

How to set different styles in python seaborn? For example, it's possible to set a style with `sns.set_style("whitegrid")` or `sns.set_style('ticks')`. But how to set both whitegrid and ticks?

`sns.set_style(["whitegrid", 'ticks'])` showing `ValueError: style must be one of white, dark, whitegrid, darkgrid, ticks`

Comment: Only one style can be set. The style you want to specify is a white background with or without grid lines, but what is your intention to set both? To customize to one style, use the rc parameter. See the reference for [more information](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html#seaborn.set_style).

Comment: The styles are just sets of matplotlib rcParams. They can't be set at the same time because they provide different values for the parameters (e.g. the spines are black with `ticks` but gray with `whitegrid`). But you can pick and choose the ones you want from each and pass them to `mpl.rc`.